# My UI components are not properly displayed in the screen.(even within the screen bounds)

Tags: android-widget

For example,

My emulator sets 800*480 (w*h) as the screen size.

Portrait case : The total width of my UIs is 412dp.
Landscape case : The total height is 413

Above two cases are within the 480. But inner components are still cut..

If anyone knows the answer it would be greatly
appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer from google documents [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels

Because I put my drawable icon (E.g 410*212 using actual pixels as unit)in the res/drawable folder.

so some area of my components will be cut.

To solve this problem, I just move all my icons into the res/drawable-high folder.

I cut following information from the official web sites:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp